# Formatting datetime in pandas columns as Quarters

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format, date-formatting

I have a `DataFrame` with columns in `DateTime` index, representing quarters such as: `2000-03-31 00:00:00`

How can I do to transform this into `'2000q1'`?

I have looked around the docs, but they only mention [`DateTimeIndex.quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.quarter.html)

`format='%Y%q'` does not work. Neither does the option `on='%Y%q`

Comment: Should the pandas docs be updated here? (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html) to remove the `'%q'`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `to_period("Q")`:

```
df.index = df.index.to_period("Q")
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [1,2,3]}, 
                  index=pd.to_datetime(["2000-03-31 00:00:00", "2000-05-31 00:00:00", "2000-08-31 00:00:00"]))

df.index = df.index.to_period("Q")
df
#       y
#2000Q1 1
#2000Q2 2
#2000Q3 3
```

---

To convert a normal column `col`, use `dt` to access the `Datetime` objects in the series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [1,2,3], 'col': pd.to_datetime(["2000-03-31 00:00:00", "2000-05-31 00:00:00", "2000-08-31 00:00:00"])})


df['col'] = df['col'].dt.to_period("Q")

df
#      col  y
#0  2000Q1  1
#1  2000Q2  2
#2  2000Q3  3
```