# Add custom formatting options to python datetime class

Tags: python, datetime, formatting, python-datetime, extending

I'm trying to add custom formatting options to the python datetime class, specifically a %Q option that will output the quarter. I'm assuming this can be done by extending the datetime class but I'm not sure how to go about doing this, any ideas?

Comment: Such a thing already exists e.g. in pandas, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/41369227/10197418

Comment: client is specifically asking to have the functionality added to the datetime class

Comment: Does it have to be part of the existing strptime/strftime methods? Because I think it might be difficult to extend them; to me it seems extending the class by another method would be easier.